# Convert Global Objects to Bundles To Use In Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have multiple files like:

- library0.js
- library1.js
- ...
- libraryn.js

Each populates part of a global object "MY_GLOBAL" like this example:

### library0.js

```
// check that the MY_GLOBAL namespace exists
if (typeof(MY_GLOBAL) === 'undefined') {
    var MY_GLOBAL = {};
}

MY_GLOBAL.TIMEOUT =  120000; // 2 minutes

MY_GLOBAL.extractErrMsg = function(reqResponse) {
    console.log(reqResponse);
};
```

### library1.js

```
// check that the MY_GLOBAL namespace exists
if (typeof(MY_GLOBAL) === 'undefined') {
    var MY_GLOBAL = {};
}

MY_GLOBAL.STRING =  'STRING';

MY_GLOBAL.exposed = function() {
    console.log("This is exposed);
};
```

Currently in my index.html file, I add all these files in script includes. Therefore all my other js files can simple call:

```
MY_GLOBAL.extractErrMsg
```

or any other function/object on MY_GLOBAL.

I am moving to a WebPack build where I want to make all these files as bundles and import them globally so all my files can use it like I do now. What is the way to convert my library files to bundles which can then be globally imported in WebPack so that I do not need to modify each other file to import MY_GLOBAL?

Thank you!

Comment: I believe it should be enough to use [imports-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/imports-loader/) and [exports-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/exports-loader/).

Comment: Do you think there is a way to convert to a more appropriate bundle format? I would like to package these as modules individually